# Salesorce CTI Integration

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, salesforce1-app, integration, cti

We are working with a client that needs to reach out to his prospective customers via phone which must be integrated with the Salesforce Lightning.I have installed Open CTI package in my dev org but not able to make actual calls through it. Can anyone please suggest me the ways through which I can achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are referring to the [Open CTI Demo Adapter](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_cti.meta/api_cti/sforce_api_cti_demo_adapter.htm) you won't be able to make calls only by installing the package. It's just a demonstration of how your CTI client can look like.

To make actual calls you need to have an access to Hotline Provider and VoIP Provider accounts (sometimes it can be one and the same, it varies a lot). Having that you must use Hotline Provider's API to integrate it with your system.

You can also rely on already existing Click-To-Dial packages. For instance, in UK the examples are [Cloud Call](https://www.cloudcall.com/), [Vonage](https://www.vonage.com/) or [Natterbox](https://www.natterbox.com/). Unfortunately, most of them (if not all) are paid ones. But assuming you don't have a whole CTI-dedicated team, it's considered a better practice to use an already developed package.